# Storing UIBezierPath as Blob to SQLite in SWIFT (IOS)

Tags: ios, object, serialization, blob

I don't know where to start, so I simply asking for giving me a hint where to start :-)

I like to store and read back an Object like UIBezierPath into a blob field of SQLite Database.
I have done this already with Android Pathes and had to write my own Serializer/Deserializer for this.

Is there already any standard way to do this ?

Comment: Who downvoted this question? This sort of thing is hart to figure out for new devs, and a common problem that needs to be solved. (Archiving different kinds of objects.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the docs for `UIBezierPath`, it says the class conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol. This means that you can use the `NSKeyedArchiver` method 
`archivedDataWithRootObject` to convert a bezier path to `NSData`. Saving `NSData` to a BLoB is easy.

You'd then use the `NSKeyedUnarchiver` method `unarchiveObjectWithData` to convert the data back to a bezier curve.

If your bezier curves are large and complex you might want to find another way of storing them. Large BLoBs tend to slow down SQL/Core Data databases unless you're careful with your design.

Comment: Thank you very much. You brought me on the right path. Thats exacly what I looked for. And now learned about this general NSData, which is kind of standard stream, is it ?

Comment: NSData is an object that holds binary data. You can send the contents of NSData to a stream, or capture streaming content into NSData, but they are different.

Comment: Great. Thanks for explanation.